# Is there any way to disable write-access to source code from within Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Is there any easy solution to prevent Xcode from writing to source files in a project? I want to edit source files externally and only use Xcode for debugging and so I want to prevent any accidental modifications getting saved via xcode. (Obviously I want Xcode to pickup external changes to files when I build/debug)

One possible solution that I thought of was to enable app sandbox entitlements on xcode and manually maintain a list of directories that it should not write to. Is this feasible? Any other ideas?

On the sandboxing thing, I'm not sure if Xcode is disqualified as per  [Apple's Sandboxing Requirements](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW6).

Comment: Set up source control. When xcode messes with your stuff, simply reset.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my problem isn't that I have no way of reverting those changes. I do. I'd like to avoid the modifications in the first place for reasons out of scope for the question.

Comment: This feels like it should really be asked on SO.  The general rule of thumb is if you're in front of your IDE ask it on SO, if you're in front of a white board ask it on Programmers.  I've voted to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to prevent XCode from getting all into your source, writing temp files and whatnot.

One option would be to create a simple shell script that pushes your source to a directory for XCode to use.  Since you're not using XCode for development (debugging only), just copy your entire project tree into a temporary directory and then open that in XCode.

Something like (push_to_xcode.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

#first, wipe existing project from your temp directory

rm -rf /tmp/xcode_temp_code

#then, copy your existing project into the temp folder

cp -R /path/to/your/project/myProject /tmp/xcode_temp_code

#lastly, launch the project

open /tmp/xcode_temp_code/myProject.xcodeproj
```

Once you've created the script, change it to executable by typing `chmod +x push_to_xcode.sh`

Then open a terminal, cd to the directory where you saved the script, and type `./push_to_xcode.sh` or double click on it in finder.

That will launch Xcode with this project.  No changes you make in XCode, either purposefully or accidentally, will affect your original code.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing now. It is a pre-build task so its all automated. But it just adds to the build times because I have large resource asset files and now I either have to write my own program to compare for changes or add some other unneeded complexity to the build chain.

Comment: Wow...I have an app with about 650MB of resources that I tested with the above script and it took less than 15 seconds to copy everything and launch XCode.  Perhaps only copying what has been changed would be the way to go, but that seems like a lot of unneeded complexity, as you said.  Personally, I'd just start the copy and then go make some tea.